# Conda - numpy import issues

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, anaconda, conda, modulenotfounderror

I installed Anaconda and activated the environment. When I attempt to run a python script which imports numpy in Visual Studio Code I am facing the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\UserX\python test.py 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core'; 'numpy' is not a package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\UserX\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have no issues with running the same directly:

```
(base) C:\Users\python   
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Conda info confirms the same python version in use...

```
(base) C:\Users\UserX\conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\UserX\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\UserX\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
```

the chosen python interpreter is the one installed with Anaconda and no other version of python exists.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

I tried reinstalling numpy, matplotlib, Anaconda, Visual Studio Code, deleting Anaconda directory and any other potential solutions I could found with a search engine. Is there anything obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I missed an important fact that another file within the same directory had a name numpy.py which was causing issues as per the error message. Oh boy... I should have noticed that earlier. I have renamed the file and the issue is resolved.

```
File "C:\Users\UserX\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
```